# HDD SMART test shows read error; should I toss the disk or scan for bad blocks?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, smart, bad-blocks

After triggering SMART test (long) using smartctl, I have the following smartctl -a output:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-142-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Black
Device Model:     WDC WD1003FZEX-00K3CA0
...
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   168   168   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       2558
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       888
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       5663
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       888
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       136
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       3072
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   122   104   000    Old_age   Always       -       21
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      5552         50184
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      5088         50184
```

...

It says the SMART tests have failed with a read error @ sector 50184. Does this indicate that this (fairly new) disk needs replacing or just that there are some bad blocks that need to be marked as such?

Comment: Between spin up time and reallocated sector count in pre-fail, I would return it under the warranty.

Answer (score 1):

To interpret SMART data, keep in mind that the value is normalized to 100 ("standard"), and lower is worse. When it gets near or below the threshold, then it's time to worry.

I have no idea what Moab sees in there, but at least according to the SMART values I see, everything looks fine: You have used the drive for a bit, but all other values are way above 100.

The raw reallocated sector count value is actually zero, so this one bad sector that was found wasn't even reallocated.

You know the LBA address of the bad sector. To be safe, try to find out if there's a file at this LBA (e.g. with the `debugfs` tool for ext2/3/4). Then use `dd` to read this block, verify you get an error, and zero it again with `dd` by writing to it from `/dev/zero`. If you are not familiar with `dd`, double check you have the correct block size, count etc. (or you'll destroy data elsewhere).

Now you should get a reallocated sector count of one (because writing a bad block causes a reallocation), a working sector (read it again with `dd`), and you can restart the SMART test and see if it finds other bad sectors.

Also replace the file where the bad sector was with a new version (e.g. reinstall the package if it was a system file).